# How to check if a TCP connection is local?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

For a project, I need to know whether the network connection is from the local computer or from a remote computer.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved by utilizing the `getpeername` and the `getsockname` functions.

This snipped does exactly what I need it to:

```
 bool checkForLocalConnection(SOCKET Sock) {
      sockaddr_in RemAddr, LocAddr;
      int Len = sizeof(RemAddr);
      getpeername(Sock, (sockaddr *)&RemAddr, &Len);
      getsockname(Sock, (sockaddr *)&LocAddr, &Len);
      return (RemAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr == LocAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
 }
```

The endianess of the result is always the same, which is why you don't even have to convert it to native endianess.

Why this works and why it's necessary:

If you connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, `getpeername` will always yield the address `127.0.0.1` (converted to an unsigned long, obviously).
That means, you could just check for `htonl(2130706433);` and be done with it (Minding the endianess). However if you enter the actual address...or any of your other local addresses your NIC might have, `getpeername` will return that address, instead of 127.0.0.1.

`getsockname` will return the local interface this socket is connected on, which means it will choose the correct interface and tell you its address, which is equal only if you're connected from a local machine.

I hope this will help someone, since I had to search forever to find that little info.
It should work for most common cases. (There are some exceptions)

List of exceptions:

Multi-Address network cards. These are on the same machine but either not on the same NIC or bound to a different IP. There isn't that much you can do about that.

Calling localhost on a different IP than 127.0.0.1. `getsockname` will always return 127.0.0.1, regardless of which 127.x.x.x you're calling. As a 'guard' against that, you can check specifically for the 127 in the first octet of the peer address.

Many thanks for the help with this goes to harper.

Comment: Also keep in mind that your system might be forwarding some ports, which would look local but ain't really.

Comment: It's common to have 127.0.0.1 but not necessary. See http://superuser.com/questions/31824/why-is-localhost-ip-127-0-0-1 to find more localhosts. Your comparison should check only for the first byte if it's 127.

Comment: @harper That's why I offered this solution. It should work for about all cases, even if 127.0.0.1 isn't the localhost.

Comment: But peername and sockname doesn't need to have the *same* sin_address. "127.1.1.1"!="127.0.0.1".

Comment: Further you should elaborate the problem with multi-homed nodes. When you have a node with two network adapters (or IP addresses per adapter) and bind a server to one socket address, and bind the client to the other IP address of the adapter or to IP address of the other adapter, get get a local connection from the local host. peeername and sockname will differ in the sin_addr part.  Multi-homed is an ugly problem when you're fiddling with addresses and assumptions on values. That's my expriences.

Comment: @harper I will be honest, I haven't checked if 127.1.1.1 will even connect me to the localhost or what result sockname and peername return in this case. I'll try it out if I find the time, but if I understand things correctly, it should still work. But I'll try it out.

Comment: @harper Yeah, the multi-address NICs are not addressed in this approach. Let's just settle it would work for the most common cases, okay? But thank you very much for bringing these problems to my (and everyone else's) attention.

Comment: @harper Okay, I checked and you were right. 127.1.1.1 will yield a false result. I'll add it to the list of special cases. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To handle the multi-homed situation, you can enumerate the available local IPs using OS-specific APIs, like `GetAdaptersAddresses()` or `getifaddrs()`. If the IPs reported by `getsockname()` and `getpeername()` are both local, then you have a local connection, otherwise you have a remote connection.